# Connecting buttons to timer and calculating time in percentage

Tags: ios, swift, timer, percentage, calculation

This is probably somewhat of a stupid question, as I am a total newbie in coding, BUT:

I have just programmed a timer in swift which is working fine, but the next step of my little project is to make three buttons that will connect to the timer, that calculates the percentage of the total time that has elapsed. for example for a ball possession calculator with the buttons "Home" for when the home team has the ball, "Away" for when the away team has the ball, and finally a button "not in play" for when the ball is out of play, which will pause the calculation of possession. Is there someone that can help me with connecting the buttons to the timer, and helping me with the code to calculate the percentage?

I have created two labels that will show the percentage. I hope someone can help this novice :) Thanks!

the timer:

@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

```
var timer = Timer()
var minutes: Int = 0
var seconds: Int = 0
var timerIsOn = false

var stopwatchString: String = ""

@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if timerIsOn == false {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    timerIsOn = true
}

@IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton)
{
timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 0
    lbl.text = ("00:00")
    timerIsOn = false
}

func action()
{
    seconds += 1
    lbl.text = String(seconds)
    if seconds == 60 {

        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0

    }

    let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

    stopwatchString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
    lbl.text = stopwatchString
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to have 3 Buttons with each a timer, i suppose you would have to make 3 timer variables, and on the button actions continue one and pause the others. Please explain  a bit further to help you better :]

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit of a bad explanation :)
Basically what i am trying to do, is to make a possession timer for soccer/football, just to practise some coding.

So the layout is basically this:

on the top of the screen, I have a timer that shows the total elapsed time of the game, which you press when the game starts. The timer has two buttons underneath, which starts the timer, and resets the timer after the half is finished.

Underneath that, i have three more buttons that you need to push to "calculate" the ammount of possession your team has, showed in percent of the total time :)

Comment: I guess the formula to calculate the percentage will be the total time one of the "home team" or "away/visiting team" buttons are being active / by the total elapsed time * 100

But i'm not sure what to connect to make that happen, or how to implement this formula.

I think i somehow need to connect these "Home team" and "away/visiting team" buttons to the timer i created to calculate the time they are being pushed. Or do i need to make a new timer that is hidden?

I hope you understand! :) Vegard. @J.Paravicini

Answer (score 1):

Ok since you added more information on how you would like to do it i'll try to explain a few things. First of all i wouldn't be using Timer, since Timers in swift are meant for countdowns, which you aren't looking for. What I would do is try first make a working Stopwatch, I recommend you read [this](http://rshankar.com/simple-stopwatch-app-in-swift/) tutorial on how to do that.

If you have got a working StopWatch class, you need 3 instances of this class: The total time; The Home possess time; And the away possess time.
If you have these it will be fairly easy to get the percentage of them. The home percentage would be something like this:

```
homeStopWatch.elapsedTime/totalStopWatch.elapsedTime * 100
```

The away would be subtracting the former calculated valued from 100. I hope I could clarify your doubts a bit, and please ask if there is a misunderstanding.

Regards -Jorge